# How to use declared variable for SQL statement by using "IN" condition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am trying to write some code but it doesn't work. It only those `TypeT` description. How can I display the `TypeT` and `TypeS` condition for below case?

```
DECLARE @PaymentType VARCHAR(20) = '';

SELECT @PaymentType = LISTID 
FROM LIST 
WHERE LISTCONFIG IN ('TypeT', 'TypeS')

SELECT * 
FROM LIST 
WHERE LISTID IN  (@PaymentType)
```

Comment: thanks for the information.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below

```
SELECT * FROM LIST 
WHERE LISTID IN  (select LISTID FROM LIST WHERE LISTCONFIG IN 'TypeT','TypeS'))
```

Or you can use the below in only sql server 2016

```
DECLARE @PaymentType VARCHAR(20)
SELECT @PaymentType= isnull(@PaymentType+',','')+LISTID FROM list WHERE LISTID IN ('TypeT','TypeS')
SELECT * FROM LIST WHERE LISTID IN  (select value from STRING_SPLIT(@PaymentType, ',')  )
```

Comment: hi, sorry i want the Types to be store in variable ..so i can use that variable for other purpose.

Comment: We can only go with one at a time with a variable or you have to store them with delimiter seperated and then split them based on delimiter or dynamic sql.

Comment: thanks for the reply.. i've found the solution !

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT * 
FROM LIST 
WHERE 
    LISTID IN  (SELECT LISTID FROM LIST WHERE LISTCONFIG IN ('TypeT','TypeS'))
```

However, I think that this is still too complex. Have you tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM LIST WHERE LISTCONFIG IN ('TypeT','TypeS')
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.. i've found the solution !

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it using `IN`, you'll have to do it with dynamic SQL. This also means creating the comma separated string. Which is doable, but an easier way is this:

```
DECLARE @PaymentType TABLE (ListID INT) ;

INSERT @PaymentType (ListID)
SELECT LISTID FROM LIST WHERE LISTCONFIG IN ('TypeT','TypeS')

SELECT  LST.* 
FROM    LIST Lst
JOIN    @PaymentType AS PT
    ON  PT.ListID = Lst.ListID
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.. i've found the solution !

Answer (score 1):

Another sollution is using dynamic strings. If your sql version is below 2016

```
DECLARE @PaymentType VARCHAR(20)
SELECT @PaymentType= isnull(@PaymentType+',','')+LISTID FROM list WHERE LISTID IN ('TypeT','TypeS')
exec('SELECT * FROM LIST WHERE LISTID IN  ('+@PaymentType+')')
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.. i've found the solution !